# How to determine if System.Object is System.Type

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a general IValueConverter for WPF, and i'm coming unstuck on comparing the value to a particular type.

The makeup of my objects in look something like this

```
public interface IAwesome
{
    int AwesomeAmount { get; set; }
}

public class MyAwesomeClass : IAwesome
{
    public int AwesomeAmount { get; set; }
}
```

My method looks something like this

```
public bool CompareToType(object value, Type type);
```

If I had...

```
var mac = new MyAwesomeClass();
bool isAwesome = CompareToType(mac, typeof(IAwesome));
```

Similarly I could write

```
var stream = new FileStream();
bool isStream = CompareToType(stream, typeof(Stream));
```

How do I write my CompareToType method to determine if the class implements the Interface or inherits from a base object?

Apologies if i'm missing somethign blindingly obvious, but i'd appreciate some help anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.TYPE.ISASSIGNABLEFROM%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) method.

Example:

```
type.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType());
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are looking for `is`?

```
var stream = new FileStream();
bool isStream = stream is Stream;
```

you could also try

```
isStream = typeOf(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(stream.GetType());
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your looking for this:

```
if (mac is IAwesome) {}
```

Or:
    var t = mac as IAwesome;
    if (t != null) {}

Comment: Hehe, everyone  rushed for the same answer :)

Comment: It is not possible to use `is` if you look at the signature of the `CompareToType` method

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isAwesome = mac is IAwesome;
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a class implements an interface:

```
var obj = new MyInteracedClass();
typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType());

or

typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyInteracedClass));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy implementation is

```
public bool CompareToType(object obj, Type type)
{
    return type != null
        && obj != null
        && type.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType());
}
```